# iOS Simulator not functioning in Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am trying to build an app, but I can't test my app because iOS Simulator isn't working.

When I try to run iOS Simulator, it don't even get a black iPhone screen, the whole iOS Simulator window is black. I can't get it to show anything. This makes coding an app extremely difficult, especially for a beginner like me.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might happen? The main interface is set to main.storyboard, and I don't get any errors when I try to run iOS Simulator, it just shows a black screen. Also, when I try to stop it I have to use Cmd+Q because the stop button doesn't work.

Are these two related, and can anyone fix it?

Screenshot of the problem:

[image]
<sub>(source: [hostthenpost.com](http://hostthenpost.com/uploads/4d2e2cb62d6f03a7f330affc90276f3b.png))</sub>

Computer specs:
Mac Mini (Late 2014) running OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 and Xcode 6.3.

Comment: show us your storyboard and your code pls

Comment: Try to create a new single view application, add something in the storyboard just for visual indication and try to run it, does it give the same result?

Comment: @itinance The application is literally a single-view hello world application. It has nothing but a splash screen and a label in the storyboard that says Hello World. It's a little sad, I know, but that's my beginner level.
Creating a new app is unnecessary because of the simplicity of the app. It does the same result because the application is about as simple as it gets.

Also, I have tried this without the splash screen, just the label and it still renders the same result.

Comment: Try to clear your project `Cmd + Shift + K` and try to use emulate another device

Comment: Have you downloaded the newer simulator which you can find in (cmd + ,)

Comment: iOS Simulator version 8.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! I just have to wait a thousand years for it to load, and then it works fine.

Comment: A thousand years? Surely you exaggerate? It can't be more than 600 years, 700 at max!

Answer (score 2):

I had to quit Xcode and relaunch it after upgrading to 6.3 before my simulator would work. Also make sure you quit the simulator. The old Xcode 6.2 simulator is likely not compatible with 6.3

Comment: I've closed Xcode a million times and I never had Xcode 6.2, I bought my Mac and downloaded Xcode.

Comment: With arrival of Swift, I see that XCode is not stable any more, even in release versions.

Comment: Xcode 4.0 was a disaster. It's slowly gotten better since, although 6.2 and 6.3 do seem to have stability problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting your Mac, then try to run the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my Mac helped me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know the above (or below) solutions all probably work, but I found a way to fix the issue that might be a little faster than restarting Xcode, your Mac, or waiting somewhere between 600-1000 years:

If you change the scale size of the iPad (`Window > Scale`) it seems to fix the issue.